# Determine the new autoincrement primary key value "before" creating a new row

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a **Winforms TreeView** and I wish to store the node data into an SQLite table, so that I can restore the TreeView when the application starts up next time. I use the TreeView to drive most of the desktop application and use index pointer fields within a class attached to the TreeNodes to access other tables in the database when a user clicks on a node.

The problem I am trying to avoid is a lot of "round tripping" between the TreeView and the TreeNode_Table everytime a new TreeNode is created.  It would be best if I know ahead of time what the **next autoincrement primary key will be** in the TreeNode_Table ***before*** I create the TreeNode. That way I can create and add the node to the tree then copy the data into a new TreeNode_Table row in a single pass.  No round trips between the table and the TreeView to sync up values like the primary key, node level, node index, and other node and row values.

I tried:

```
string strFindLastRowInserted = @"SELECT MAX([id]) FROM [TreeNode_Table];";
var findLastRowInsertedCmd = new SQLiteCommand(strFindLastRowInserted, _cnn);
object resultObj = findLastRowInsertedCmd.ExecuteScalar();
findLastRowInsertedCmd.Dispose();
if( resultObj != null)
NodeTagDataObj.DataPtr = (long)resultObj + 1;
```

But adding one to **MAX([id])** breaks down if some of the most recently created nodes/rows have been previously deleted. I'm using the **System.Data.Sqlite** library to access the data file.

Thank you for your help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out by probing around within Sqlite's table metadata. To reliably obtain the **next** autoincrement key value ***before*** the new row is created, the following SQL can be used:

```
SELECT [seq] + 1 FROM [sqlite_sequence] WHERE [name] = 'my_table_name';
```

I added and tested the following static helper method to my SqliteHelper class and everything works as expected and the logic survives recent row deletions, disconnections, and application restarts.

#### SqliteHelper.cs:

```
internal static long GetNextAutoincrementValue(SQLiteConnection cnn, 
                                               string tableName)
{
    long returnValue = -1;
    SQLiteCommand myCommand = cnn.CreateCommand();  
    myCommand.CommandText = 
        @"SELECT [seq] + 1 FROM [sqlite_sequence] WHERE [name] = @MyTableName;";

    SQLiteParameter myParam = new SQLiteParameter("@MyTableName",
                                                  System.Data.DbType.String);
    myParam.Value = tableName.Trim();
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(myParam);
    object resultObj = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    myCommand.Dispose();
    if( resultObj != null)
        returnValue = (long)resultObj;
    return returnValue;
}
```

I hope that others will find this useful...

-DougC

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to ask for the new row key after it's been inserted with LastInsertRowId property off the SQLiteConnection object.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that break down after the connection has been closed and the application restarted?  Especially if some of the more recently created treenodes/rows have been deleted? For example, the application starts up and then the user wishes to create a new node/row. Additional rows after that one will work fine, but what about the "first" new node/row after application restart?

Comment: You won't have any issues if you've set the table to use auto increment as the key, as per http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Er, should have said "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY".

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am using AUTOINCREMENT in the treenode table in hope that I can create the node "first" and then the row in one pass.  Adding nodes to a treeview creates a lot of housekeeping data like levels and indexes and node key values that I wish to add to the table to recreate the treeview on startup. I need to create the treenode "first" and then the row or else I am stuck with multiple round trips between the two adjusting data.

Comment: All the feedback I have so far states that I need to create the row first and then the treenode.  Does anyone know how I can create the treenode "first" by reliably predicting what the next AUTOINCREMENT value will be?